# how can I count occurrence of some word in each row by a perl script?

Tags: perl

The file contains several rows like this,

```
  TT      AA      TT      GG      CC      AA
  AA      GG      CC      TT      GG      CC
  GG      AA      TT      TT      CC      TT
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. What output do you expect for the given input?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    my %count_of;
    $count_of{$_}++ for split; 

    print "Row $.:\n";
    foreach my $key ( sort {$count_of{$b} <=> $count_of{$a} } keys %count_of ) { 
       print "\t$key: $count_of{$key}\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
  TT      AA      TT      GG      CC      AA
  AA      GG      CC      TT      GG      CC
  GG      AA      TT      TT      CC      TT
```